# android sidebar menu icon and text not align properly

Tags: android, android-menu

[image]

In Above picture clearly show the text and icon not properly align so how to align text and image align properly.

List view code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: can we have code please?

Comment: post your xml code that contains your item. I mean that textview and imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding just android:layout_marginTop and work fine.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the layout of the adapter, Just put this xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding_left="5dp"
    android:padding_right="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/home"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/home_selected"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawer_drawable_padding"
    android:drawableStart="@mipmap/home_selected"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_field"
    android:text="@string/home"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Use **drawableLeft** it will automatically align your TextView with the image

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding_left="5dp"
    android:padding_right="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/home"
android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Predefine Activity In android Studio for **Navigation Drawer**(side bar)...

[image: Navigation Drawer Activity for sidebar]